# Why does my Symfony native Session change?

Tags: php, symfony, session, firefox, paypal

I'm using Symfony Session component with NativeStorage.
The initialization is very simple (session property has type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session)

```
$this->session->start();
```

I'm facing a session issue during payment redirects, my application redirects user to Paypal payment, if the user push "abort" link in Paypal page it will be redirected to the abort page of the initial application.

During this second redirect somehow **the session is refreshed and a new cookie and a session-id is activated**.

I'm working with Firefox *without* private mode. I have tried to open the page manually in a new browser tab but the session is discarded in the same way.

What can cause a session expiration during a page redirect? The cookie generated is the standard cookie made by Symfony Session class and PHP:

[image]

Domain and protocol (https) dont change. The URL path changes from initial page to abort page.

**UPDATE:**

The issue seems to be connected to Firefox.
I have tested it with Chrome and works, I have tested the case with Firefox in privacy mode and it works... so I guess it is something wrong with my firefox sessions.

Comment: So if the user doesn't abort and the order is paid then the session stays intact when redirected back to the confirmation page?

Comment: Yes sir. Weird!

Comment: Why are you calling `session->start()`, and not `requestStack->getSession()`? You shouldn't generally start the session explicitly, as it's started automatically whenever you read/write/access the session. (Or simply `$this-session->get()`/`$this->session->set()` in older Symfony versions). What version of Symfony are you on?

Comment: What's the code of the controller in charge of the abort page?

Comment: Guys, the problem is limited to firefox, with chrome it works! I have tried also Firefox in privacy mode and it works. So I guess it is something wrong with firefox!